# bathroom sink has almost no cold water

Tags: faucet, sink, bathroom-fixtures

I have a interesting problem, my bathroom sink cold water tap has good water pressure and water flow but when you turn the tap it goes from cool to warm to hot rather quickly without ever touching the hot water tap.

When you turn the hot water tap initially the water that comes out is colder than the cold tap and then it warms up normally.

Any suggestion why its doing this, and how would one fix it?